# My Windows 10 version 21H1 build 19043.2006 does not have rearranging desktops

Tags: windows, windows-10

I googled for my OS build and some websites say it supports rearranging desktops by both drag-and-drop and shortcut keys, but mine does not have this feature.

Is there any other way I can do that?

Comment: The feature you want is present in Windows 11 but not (or not yet) in Windows 10.

Comment: What websites exactly? Sounds like those websites have incorrect info

Comment: @Ramhound https://techtipsnreview.com/windows-10-21h1-reveals-some-notable-new-additions/

Comment: FYI: The author is talking about arranging **virtual desktops**

Comment: As far as I can see, that feature remains limited to Windows 11.